# XAMPP SMTP Blocked by Firewall or wrong settings

Tags: xampp, smtp, phpmailer

(PS using xampp)
Apparently my machine won't send out emails using the Mailing APIs(PHPmailer,Swift) and even PHP's own mail() function. But whenever I run my emailing script on another machine, it works with no errors.

Tried it on other machines such as my univ's pcs, friend's pc and my other laptop.

Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be 
    established with host smtp.gmail.com

Tried everything,but still to no avail on my current machine.

Answer (score 0):

What this tells you is that there is nothing wrong with your script, but that your hosting provider blocks outbound SMTP. This is a very common problem, and it's covered extensively in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host).

How you actually fix it depends on your ISP - it may be that you just need to ask them to unblock it (Scaleway), or that you need to send via their servers (GoDaddy), or in the worst case, that you need to find a new hosting provider...